# Incomplete subspace of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing

I have a subspace of Banach space ($l^{\infty}$) that has all the infinite bounded sequences which has finite number of nonzero elements.

I need to prove that this subspace is incomplete. In order to do so I need to find a Cauchy sequence that does not converge on this subspace (subset).

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the right track. An important point in this case is that the sequence does not converge in the subspace *only*; it will converge if you consider it in the full space, as it's a Banach space.

To put this differently, you will want to construct a sequence in your subspace that converges to an element outside of your subspace.

To this end you'll need an element of $l^{\infty}$ that is not eventually $0$, yet whose terms become ever smaller (in absolute value), technically its limit is $0$. Every such element, not eventually $0$ and the terms tend to $0$ will work.

Indeed, the space of all sequence with limit $0$ is the closure of your subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Consider the following sequence:

$(x_n) = (1, \frac{1}{2},\ldots, \frac{1}{n}, 0, \ldots)$

That will converge to the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})$, which is not in the given subspace.